# Storage options for rich text

Tags: android, serialization, storage

I am building a note-taking app for android and trying to find the best way to store the notes.

Planned note structure:

- Metadata

  - Title
  - Note color
  - Last modified
- Text content - HTML/markdown
- Attached images

Metadata should be accesible very fast, ideally without having to load the whole document.

So far I can see the following options:

- SQLite for everything
- SQLite for metadata, files for text and images.
- Metadata and content each in separate files, encapsulated in a directory or a zipfile.

Which one should I choose for best performance?

Comment: What performance? (Wall-clock time? Disk I/O? CPU? RAM? Something else?) And performance for what operations? (Reading? Writing? Searching?)

Comment: @CommonsWare, operations are reading and writing in about equal amounts. Most probably, I'd like to add "search in all notes" feature later.
And by performance I mean decent user experience while not using too much resources. So it's more of a 'best practice' question.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I think disk I/O performance is certainly the bottleneck, so I need to optimize it